# Parsing a csv file, how to determine date column formats?

Tags: html, jquery, excel, csv

I am currently working on parsing a CSV file, putting that in a temp Jquery Datatable, then submitting it to the database after the user verifies the data.

My current issue is from two sides, the date column of the spreadsheet and the cobbled structure of the spreadsheet. The date columns could come in a variety of flavors, from YYYYMMDD, to MM/DD/YYYY, to that silly excel serial date format (XXXXX) [pretty much days since January 1, 1900].

I can handle the first two cases, but the excel serial date format is giving me issues with trying to figure out if the data is in this format in the first place.

I know how to convert the excel format to a usable datetime format in jquery. Anyone have any tips? I know one way is to get them to manually convert the cells in the CSV to a single type, but the document is extremely lengthy and they are also very busy.

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with Jquery. But I think in order to help you better, could you please list some example of date format that it  can be. And also it is for the same column or for a different column?

Comment: Can you convert the xxxxx into a date, then check if it's in a "sensible" range (eg +-50 years from today)?

Comment: If you examine the date columns in the CSV file, **by using Notepad or Notepad++**, are the date formats still variable?  If not, it suggests you need to change the method of importing the csv into Excel.  If it is, it suggests you need to examine the method of generating the CSV. Without a stable format, date data can often be ambiguous.